# Angular4でスリープさせたい

Tags: angular4

数秒後に処理をさせたく、スリープのような処理を入れたいのですが、
どのように実施すればよいのでしょうか？

```
  private sleep(milliseconds: number) {
    return new Promise<void>(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(), milliseconds);
    });
  }

await sleep(1000);
```

のような記載をみつけたのですが
awaitが認識されませんでした…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ブラウザーでsleepは出来ません。

記載のコードは以下と同等です。

```
setTimeout(function(){
    await後の処理
}, 1000)
```

Comment: hiroさま、ありがとうございます。勉強になりました。